# Remove duplicates while prioritizing a specific value in a different column in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I need to remove duplicates from the Reference column, but prioritize keeping the row with a specific value in NODCCODE if it exists for that group of reference numbers. If that NODCCODE value does not exist, it doesn't matter which row is saved. In the end there should only be unique reference numbers but all instances of the target NODCCODE and associated reference number should still exist. There is only one instance of NODCCODE per group of reference numbers in the starting data set. In the example below I used the target NODCCODE of "8835430200"

I have the following data...

```
structure(list(Reference = c("BBM101", "BBM101", 
"BBM101", "BBM101", "BBM101"), NODCCODE = c("8835020301", 
"8835400201", "8835430201", "8835430401", "8837010102"), Number = c(1, 
16, 30, 17, 2), hogN = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Reference     NODCCODE   Number  hogN
  <chr>         <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 BBM101 8835020301      1     0
2 BBM102 8835400201     16     0
3 BBM102 8835430200     30     0
4 BBM103 8835430401     17     0
5 BBM103 8837010102      2     0
```

END RESULT:

```
structure(list(Reference = c("BBM101", "BBM102", "BBM103"), 
               NODCCODE = c("8835020301", "8835430200", "8835430401"), 
               Number = c(1, 30, 17), hogN = c(0, 0, 0)), 
          row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  Reference     NODCCODE   Number  hogN
  <chr>         <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>
1 BBM101 8835020301      1     0
2 BBM102 8835430200     30     0
3 BBM103 8835430401     17     0
```

Please let me know if more starting rows are needed. I tried keeping it very basic.

I have tried many ways including

```
df2 <- bionum[order(bionum$Reference, bionum$NODCCODE=="8835430200"),]
de.duped <- df2[!duplicated(df2$Reference),]
```

I'm getting the correct count of Reference numbers but it's putting my target number last in the Reference group and saving the first instance of each Reference, therefor the output doesn't contain ANY of my target NODCCODE value.

Can I get it to sort my target NODCCODE to the top within reference number? Then the rest of the code I am trying would keep the first instance of that NODCCODE.

I've also looked at all the other related posts I can find and just can't seem to find a way to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, I just had to add -() around bionum$NODCCODE=="8835430200" to make it sort it to the top. Simple.

```
df2 <- bionum[order(bionum$Reference, -(bionum$NODCCODE=="8835430200")),]
de.duped <- df2[!duplicated(df2$Reference),]
```